# Extra whitespace in HTML values rendered with Jade

Tags: html, node.js, whitespace, express, pug

Every time I write my HTML in Jade, I am getting extra whitespace added after each element's value.

For example, I will have a line like this in my Jade Template:

```
label(for="keyword") Keyword
```

And when it's rendered, the source will look like this:

```
<label for="keyword_1">Keyword
          </label>
```

Ran into some problems with that extra whitespace messing w/ my CSS.  Plus, it just doesn't look as tidy :)

Anyone know how I can prevent it from being inserted?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any whitespace after 'Keyword' in Jade, maybe that can be causing the problem

Comment: Thanks, double-checked to make sure I didn't have any, and I'm still having the issue.

Answer (score 11):

**Check the update at the bottom**

I assume you're using `express` - check your app settings.

```
app.set('view options', { pretty: false })
```

If you have `jade` rendering in `pretty` mode (`pretty: true`) then it will arrange your generated source (tags) with nested indention. Turning pretty printing off should resolve your problem (though make sure you don't have trailing space, as pointed out by @alessioalex).

If you have a reason requiring you to output pretty formatting (client spec, in my case) then you can try some other things. I had a similar issue with occurring with the `textarea` tag; frustrating because the whitespace is actually injected into the content of the form. The way I got around this was to embed a the literal html with the closing tag:

```
<textarea name="someField"></textarea>
```

The [docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade) can give you some more details (search for `html` in this case). There is open [issue #341](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/341) on github which suggests an approach like [this one for scalate](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/jade-syntax.html#Whitespace_Removal:__code__gt___code__and__code__lt___code_), but it doesn't currently work in `jade` (as of version `0.19.0`) .

HTH

**Update**

Ok - subtle and cool... there is a better way to keep the sexy output from `pretty: true` and avoid spacing inside of a tag (my `textarea` example)... I just tried appending a `.` to the end of the tag (see code) and it **Just Worked™** :-)

```
form(name='frmname', method='POST')
  textarea(name='someField').
```

Renders:

```
<form name="frmname" method="POST">
  <textarea name="someField"></textarea>
</form>
```

Beauty!

Why does this work? Because `jade` treats the `.` suffix on the tag as an indicator that the tag will contain a text block (only), and then no text block is provided, so it defaults to `''`, an empty string.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment!  You're right, turning off pretty mode would definitely help, but I need to keep it enabled in my case.  Interesting trick with the `.`, but I'm keeping my eyes out for something that can really scale.  Will definitely continue to look into it and post whatever I find here.

Comment: @Jon, I'm hoping the scalate style approach will be adopted officially since it seems a logical extension to the current system - we'll see. TJ is busy on so many projects just now... we'll see!

Comment: @st3 I'd just throw a note of caution since it is an *undocumented feature*: this behavior may not continue working as `jade` continues to be improved.